# Extract text after last delimiter and attach at end of line [Linux/Ubuntu]

Tags: linux, bash, sed, fasta

I have a fasta file that looks like below:

```
>sequence_1_g1
ATTTCGGATAA
>sequence_2_g1
AGGCTCTAGGA
>sequence_2_g2
TGTTCTGAAAT
>sequence_2_g3
CACCTCGGAGT
>sequence_3_new_g1
GCGGATAAAGC
```

I'd like to only extract the numbers that comes after the last delimiter and attach them to the end of each header, so that the output would look like below:

```
>sequence_1_g1_1
ATTTCGGATAA
>sequence_2_g1_1
AGGCTCTAGGA
>sequence_2_g2_2
TGTTCTGAAAT
>sequence_2_g3_3
CACCTCGGAGT
>sequence_3_new_g1_1
GCGGATAAAGC
```

I've never used linux before and so far I've only been able to find this command to separate the text that comes after the last delimiter: `sed -E 's/.*_//' filename.fasta` . Can anyone give suggestions on what commands I should look for in addition to get my desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed -E 's/.*_.([0-9]+)/&_\1/' input_file
>sequence_1_g1_1
ATTTCGGATAA
>sequence_2_g1_1
AGGCTCTAGGA
>sequence_2_g2_2
TGTTCTGAAAT
>sequence_2_g3_3
CACCTCGGAGT
>sequence_3_new_g1_1
GCGGATAAAGC
```

Answer (score 2):

***1st solution:*** With your shown samples please try following `awk` code. Written and tested in GNU `awk`, should work in any version of it.

```
awk '/^>/{$0=$0 "_" substr($0,length($0))} 1' Input_file
```

---

***2nd solution:*** Using GNU `awk`'s `match` function with regex and capturing group's values please try following.

```
awk 'match($0,/^>.*([0-9]+)$/,arr){$0=$0"_"arr[1]} 1'  Input_file
```

---

***3rd solution:*** Assuming if your lines always have `_g` separated in lines which are getting started from `>` then we can simply try following `awk` code also.

```
awk -F'_g' '/^>/{$0=$0"_"$2} 1'  Input_file
```

---

***4th solution:*** If in case `perl` one-liner is accepted you could simply use perl's capability of capturing groups(which will be created if a regex is having true match).

```
perl -pe 's/(^>.*)([0-9]+$)/\1\2_\2/'  Input_file
```

Answer (score 2):

You may try this `sed` that searches `>` at line start and if there is a match then it matches 1+ digit at end and replaces with `number_number` substring expression:

```bash
sed -E '/^>/s/[0-9]+$/&_&/' file

>sequence_1_g1_1
ATTTCGGATAA
>sequence_2_g1_1
AGGCTCTAGGA
>sequence_2_g2_2
TGTTCTGAAAT
>sequence_2_g3_3
CACCTCGGAGT
>sequence_3_new_g1_1
GCGGATAAAGC
```